# Using "ought" in a question: "Ought I celebrate?" or "Do I ought to celebrate?"

Tags: grammaticality, semi-modals

How do I ask a question using *ought*?

- *Ought I congratulate him?* (like in [this post](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic38380.html))
- But *I ought to congratulate* is easily turned into *Do I ought to congratulate*, just like *I have congratulate* becomes *Do I have to congratulate*, and in *Ought I congratulate?* the *to* is dropped.

*Do I ought to* appears to have significantly less usage, e.g. from Google Ngram. Is it grammatically incorrect? Why?

Comment: Given the rarity of the usage of this word, it may be more suitable for EL&U. However, OED note from my answer may act as an umbrella explanation for modal verbs (_May I…, Can I…, Should I…_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Do I ought to* is non-standard and is never found in formal writing or speech; it may be found occasionally in informal speech, but even there it is dialectal or sub-standard.

*Ought* is in most respects a modal auxiliary verb like *must*, *can* and *may*, and shares with them the following characteristics:

- It is *defective*—that is, it lacks certain forms which ordinary (*lexical*) verbs have: it has no infinitive, no past or present participle, and no *-s* for the 3rd person singular present.
- It is negated with simple *not* rather than with *do not*: *You ought not (to) do that.*
- It may be inverted with its subject to form a question: *Ought I (to) do that?*

It differs from most other modal verbs in two respects:

- Like *must*, it has no distinct past inflection (and for the same reason: historically it *is* the past form of its parent verb *owe*).
- In positive indicative clauses it is used with a *marked infinitive* (*to VERB*) rather than the bare infinitive (*VERB*): *You ought **to** do that*. In negative clauses and questions the *to* is often, but not always, omitted.

Accordingly, the proper form for your question is:

> *Ought I congratulate him?* OR *Ought I to congratulate him?*

The use of *ought* is decreasing, and is mostly confined to declarative sentences now. It has been largely replaced by *should*. For this reason, actual on-the-ground use is somewhat erratic, particularly with regard to the presence or absence of the *to* marker; negative and interrogative uses just aren’t used enough to ‘fix’ their forms firmly in people’s speech habits.

Comment: Why is it defective, specifically? Is it a technical term?

Comment: @theUg  Yes, *defective* is a technical term referring to the lacks which follow the term immediately in my answer. I've edited to make that clearer, thank you.

Comment: In the declarative "I ought to congratulate him", can the mark **to** be omitted? Or can that happen only in the negative "I ought not [to] congratulate him" and interrogative "Ought I [to] congratulate him?" situations?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen As I say, the infinitive marker is obligatory in positive indicative -- that is, declarative -- clauses. In practice, "I ought not ... " and "Ought I ... ?" are very rare now; you'll almost always encounter "I shouldn't ..." and "Should I ... ?"

Answer (score 5):

*Ought I…* definitely is a more common usage, and easier on the ears. I have encountered that many a time in literature. And, as you had probably seen, *Do I ought…* is not even found by Google Ngrams.

The OED actually [has a clarification](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ought), noting that the modal verbs behave differently from regular verbs:

> The verb **ought** is a modal verb and this means that, grammatically, it does not behave like ordinary verbs. In particular, the negative is formed with the word **not** alone and not also with auxiliary verbs such as **do** or **have**. Thus the standard construction for the negative is *he **ought not** to have gone*. The alternative forms *he **didn’t ought** to have gone* and *he **hadn’t ought** to have gone*, formed as if **ought** were an ordinary verb rather than a modal verb, are found in dialect from the 19<sup>th</sup> century but are not acceptable in standard modern English.

Further there is more about forming the negative:

> The negative form of verb phrases containing *ought* is formed simply by adding *not*: *you ought not to go and see the doctor*. It is not standard English to use *didn't ought to*.

However, in the definition above there is an example of usage in a way modal verb would be used in a question:

> *What ought I to do?*