# "ought" with or without "to"?

Tags: usage, modal-verbs

We usually say "ought to" not "ought". (Although more often we say "should"). I wonder when I can say "ought" without "to".

Some examples:

- 1: Ought I to tell him?
- 2: Yes, you ought to
- 3: I don't learn as often as I ought to
- 4: ‘Ought I to write to say thank you?’ ‘Yes, I think you ought (to).’ (From Oxford Learner's Dictionary)
- 5: We ought not to have ordered so much food

Can I omit "to" after "ought". Why?

Comment: There is a similar question on ELU [Is it appropriate to omit "to" after "ought"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/47748/edit). It is sometimes dropped in Am E.

Comment: As you noted, more often we say "should".  I feel like it varies on a case by case basis but a few of the examples look antiquated, out-of-fashion.

Comment: Not really a duplicate but still answering your question: [StoneyB on hiatus's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3050/2818) about ought.